# Unflatted with automapper

Tags: automapper, automapper-11

Let's say I have an EF Core model with these three properties:

```cs
public int Id { get; set; }
public string? ApplicationName { get; set; }
public string? ApplicationVersion { get; set; }
```

and in the automapper output, after calling `ProjectTo` I want it to map to `Output`:

```cs
public NameAndVersion {
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Version { get; set; }
}

public Output {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public NameAndVersion? Application { get; set; }
}
```

is there a way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although [`ProjectTo`](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html#supported-mapping-options) has a restricted list of features, this one is can be set up via a regular `MapTo`.

```
CreateMap<YourEFmodel, Output>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.Application,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(
            src => new NameAndVersion 
            {
                Name = src.ApplicationName,
                Version = src.ApplicationVersion
            }
        ));
```

Comment: Thank you.  I would have sworn I tried this previously but what you show works great.